# Generate SubSonic migration code from existing db?

Tags: subsonic, automation, legacy, migration

In [Rob Conery's post about SubSonic Migrations](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/10/03/subsonic-migrate-me/) written in October 2007 he mentions in the 'Left To Do' list that:

> I want to be able to “Reverse
>   Engineer” an existing DB into a
>   migration file

I am looking at introducing versioning control for an existing database with **a lot** tables, and SubSonic looks like the tool for me, but I'm not looking forward to writing the first migration by hand! Does anyone know if Rob or anyone got around to writing a tool for doing this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a script for the current state of the existing schema and set your first migration to run the script.

Comment: Thanks John thats a good suggestion - sometimes simple is best!